# Floating action Button visibility issue?

Tags: java, android-layout, floating-action-button

In the below code i am trying to make fab button visible during a sip call and invisible when the call is ended.some how fab7.show doesnt show anything, only fab8.hide() works inside oncallended function. Any help would be highly appreciated.

> In the below code, when the
>   Fab button was touched for more than 3 second(inside onTouchListener)
>   , i am calling sendingcall function and at the same time make fab8
>   visible.
>
> when the call is ended , by default below function oncallend function
>   is called , in that function i am hiding fab8.

```
  fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override


            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                call.setListener(myListener);

                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        down = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //this is the time in milliseconds
                        re= System.currentTimeMillis();
                        differ = System.currentTimeMillis()- down;

                        if(differ>=3000){
                            sendingCall();

                            FloatingActionButton fab8 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab8);
                             fab8.show();

                        }
                        break;

                }
```

> onCallEnded function is called everytime when the call is ended. And here i am hiding fab button

```
  public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall endedCall) {


       FloatingActionButton fab8 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab8);
        fab8.hide();  //***only hide works **
```

> ```
>      FloatingActionButton fab7 = (FloatingActionButton)  findViewById(R.id.fab7);
>      fab7.show();       //.  ******does not shows********
> ```

```
                    Log.d("call", "Call ended.................................");


}
```

Comment: you can simply use `fab8.setVisiblity(View.GONE)` or `fab8.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: no, they're deprecated @bhuvneshpattnaik. Use  fab8.show()

Comment: hi @Shine thanks it has solved half of my problem . But some how fab7show() inside the onCallEnded Function doesn't shows, only hide part works.Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So from what it looks like for me here you are using .setVisibility() in the onTouch event and the hide() function in the onCallEnded method.
So insteadt of using .hide try using setVisibility() to hide the button again.

Comment: better the opposite, as .setVisibility() is a protected method